# How to execute multiline python with -c option

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I need to execute a multiline python script with python using -c option.

Example:

```
python -c "
print()
print()
print()"
```

I do know there is a way to do this by putting everything on a single line and separating everything by a semicolon, i.e.

```
python -c "print(); print(); print()"
```

However the script I need to execute is slightly larger than 3 lines of code and needs to be written on multiple lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try your first example? That works for me. However depending on your code, you can use single quotes if there will be double quotes.

```
python -c '
print("hello")
print("two")
print("three")
'
```

You can also use a "heredoc" **without adding the `-c`** and then you don't have to worry about quotes. This is basically like reading it from a file.

```
python <<EOP
print("check")
print('one')
print('"two"')
EOP
```

The `EOP` can just be a unique string, and you terminate the input by putting it on its own line at the beginning. In the remote case that you would have `$PATH` or `*` or other bash entities in your code that you don't want to substitute, put single quotes around the **first** `EOP`

```
# Define variable in the shell (not in python)
MYVAR=Hello

# Without quotes, shell substitution happens
python <<EOP
print("$MYVAR"*3)
EOP

HelloHelloHello

# With quotes, no shell substitution
python <<'EOP'
print("$MYVAR"*3)
EOP

$MYVAR$MYVAR$MYVAR
```